# blue border in dropdown if it is not expanded, when using chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

[image]

I have a dropdown inside a form, but when using Chrome when the dropdown is closed and has focus it shows a blue border.
I would like to remove it or do change it as the last field that I show in the attached picture, dark green line with a light green halo.

I've tried several suggestions that I saw here as:

```
 *:active{
     outline: none !important;
 }
 *:focus{
    outline: none !important;
 }
```

they worked when the dropdown is expanded but not when is closed.
I don't know much of css, but here is an excerpt of my html, although I'm using wicket and I'm not sure how the component is rendered in the browser html.

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <span><label class="control-label" wicket:for="valid"><wicket:message
                                key="filter-valid-label">[Valid]
    </wicket:message></label></span>
    <select wicket:id="valid" class="form-control selectpicker">
            <option>option1</option>
            <option>option2</option>
            <option>option3</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This probably has to do with bootstraps :focus on .form-control

This is the css from bootstrap

```
.form-control:focus {
    border-color: #66afe9;
    outline: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 8px rgba(102,175,233,.6);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 8px rgba(102,175,233,.6);
}
```

Use

```
.form-control:focus {
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

Comment: It works with the text fields, but not with the drop-down.

Comment: It would help if you tell me what libs you're using. Im guessing you're using some third party dropdown .. like "bootstrap-select" ?.

Anyway if you try to learn how to use the chrome dev tools - you can find all these css attributes you have to change pretty easy.

Comment: yes you are correct, I'm indeed using BootstrapSelect class.

Answer (score 0):

Add this anywhere in your CSS code, replacing `rgba(0,100,0,.6)` with whatever shade of green you'd like :

```
.form-control.selectpicker:focus {
    border-color : rgba(0,100,0,.6);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 8px rgba(0,100,0,.6);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 8px rgba(0,100,0,.6);
}
```

It will override the Bootstrap code on `.form-control:focus` that's responsible for the blue `border-color` and `box-shadow` on your dropdown!

See [this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x7a79qt7/) for a demo!

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
.form-conrol:focus{box-shadow:none:border-color:none;}
```